# How to Telnet to Pop3 server?

Tags: telnet, pop3

I have an interview coming up and I want to play around with POP3 and SMTP protocol.

I'm trying to login to my gmail's pop3 server account using Microsoft Telnet command line program but it's **not working**.

I'm typing *pop.gmail.com 995* into the command window. I think it's not working because Gmail servers require SSL. I have tried using Putty to connect to pop.gmail.com at port 995 but this too is not working.

If Microsoft Telnet or Putty is not working, what else would?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to update to title of your question to reflect that its POP3S, not just plain POP3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install [OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), and use it to connect to servers using SSL. Type this in the command line:

```
openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995
```

By the way, Gmail's SMTP servers require authentication too (unless you're connecting from anotehr known mail server), so you'd better start with something simpler.

Comment: i tried to do it with gmail but can't actually do it with gmail. aol is better for this work.

Comment: @rezax: It works fine with Gmail and I have used this many times. I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to create an SSL tunnel and telnet through it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to learn about these protocols... fire up vmware, get hold of ubuntu, and dig in - running a simple smtp/pop3 server is not mega taxing, great practice and you'll learn LOADS more :)